# Split SelectInput Box in shiny

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

Can we split the selectinput box with + icon so that we can have multiple selection of choices across the select input boxes and filtered dynamically so that first box will have a particular list of selected of choices and the rest of choices we can select using the same choices in shiny or the rest of choices from the first selectinput.

I tried all types of searches. These selection box need to dynamically split inside shiny. It would great if i could find some reproducible example.
[image: Screenshot goes here] The image will show the required op but i need those selection in selectinput box to be accessed for modelling

Comment: You need to show some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: included my required output in a image but i not sure How to split selectinput using + button in rshiny

Comment: I found a Work around for the above required added + and - as seperate input button and selectinput box with lapply function to create the required output. thanks.